# Developing Golang backend locally for Nativescript mobile application

Tags: angular, go, localhost, nativescript

I'm working on a Nativescript mobile application, and at the same time trying to design a Golang backend.  I have no experience actually deploying a backend though, so for now i'm just trying to develop locally.  So I have some button on my emulated application:

```
import { Http } from "@angular/http"                                                                

+@Component({...}
+export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {...}{

    . . .

    // <Button ... (tap)="get_test()"></Button> 
    public get_test(){                                                                              
        this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/");                                                    
    }                                                                                               

}
```

And a small web server I copied from the [golang website](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/):

```
 package main

 import (
     "log"
     "net/http"
 )

 func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     print("recieved")
 }

 func main() {
     http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
     log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
 }
```

I start up the `go` "server":

```
go build main.go
./main
```

Now my thinking was that by clicking the button, the command line should print out `recieved` and I could use this going forward for designing my requests.  Yet nothing happens on either side.  There might be plenty of errors here in the code, and i'm not even sure you can emulate this locally.  But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: connecting to `http://localhost:8080/` will only work if you are using an IOS device use the following for android `http://10.0.2.2:8080/` if you are using the default avd or `http://10.0.3.2:8080` if you are using genymotion also you can use `go run main.go` instead of calling build each time there is a change

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that didn't work my command line remains un-printed.  I just saw that `@angular/http` might be the outdated version so i'm going to try out `@angular/common/http`

Comment: You could debug the backend apart from Angular to be sure it responds properly. @angular/http is deprecated but workable. You're using it incorrectly. There's no `.map(res => ..)`, and get_test() observable isn't subscribed. Just check the examples in the guide and paste them.

Comment: so `curl localhost:8080` prints out `recieved` so I know that's working.  I didn't think I would need to write out all the success/error code because I just want to see if I can hit my service but i'll try that.

Comment: @estus Can you explain what this means: `get_test() observable isn't subscribed`?  I'm not using a guide for the nativescript stuff, I built the app without looking at any of the backend stuff first.  Regretting that now.

Comment: An observable isn't fired if you didn't call .subscribe() on it. If you didn't check the guide, then probably should https://angular.io/guide/http . You can't develop Angular app without knowing how to develop it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your server-side code. It sounds to me like either (a) your frontend code isn't actually triggering the http request (which you should be able to detect by attaching to your browser's debugger) or (b) your frontend is trying to make the request but doesn't know how to find the server (i.e. a networking issue).